# Update more than 1 value in a dictionary in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I know how to create a dictionary that calculates total score by name (key:value) but I want to add a second value (key:(value,value))for the number of times the name appears.  Then I want to get an average score by dividing one value by the other.

```
Cleese 80
Gilliam 78
Jones 69
Jones 90
Cleese 90
Chapman 90
Chapman 100
Palin 80
Gilliam 82
Cleese 85
Gilliam 80
Gilliam 75
Idle 91
Jones 90
Palin 90
Cleese 88
```

This is my code:

```
inFile = open('grades.txt','r')

grades={}   
for line in inFile:     
    person=line.split()   
    if person[0] not in grades:     
        grades[person[0]]=float(person[1],1)     
    else:    
        grades[person[0]]=(float(person[1])+grades[person[0]],grades[person][1]+1) 

print(grades)  
inFile.close()
```

That should print (in some order):

```
Gilliam 78.75
Jones 83.0
Cleese 85.75
Chapman 95.0
Idle 91.0
Palin 85.0
```

I get an error that float only takes 1 value.  I also need to add some code that will divide my first stored value by the second for each person - an average score.

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: Share some code that you've tried so far.

Comment: Like `IQ[Gilliam] = [78]` and `IQ[Gilliam] += [82]` ?

Answer (score 0):

Use a tuple to store multiple values per key:

```
myDict['Cleese'] = (80, N)
```

To update the tuple, you can't just do `myTuple[1]++` however. You need to create a new tuple, such as `myDict['Cleese'] = (myDict['Cleese'][0], myDict['Cleese'][1]+1)`

Comment: @gkuser OP just wants to know the average of all values. A tuple is sufficient for this purpose. Probably,....I don't get completely which average shuld be computed.

Comment: And another clue is : if the new key does not still exist, add it: `if key not in myDict: myDict[key] = (0,0)` then you can do your additions